ORA-06502 error when calling a procedure from another procedure, works fine directly
Background
I am debugging an issue with a legacy Oracle procedure that converts GHS info like this:
H315;H319;H317;H360Fd;H335;H373;H410;EUH211;P201;P260;P273;P280;P333+P313;P337+P313;PROF USE

Into the actual texts that match those codes, delimited by a comma and space, so like:
Causes skin irritation, Causes serious eye irritation, ...

It's available on a general purpose schema, let's say:
COMMON.GetGHSInformation()

It does all this by building an output text (is output variable) like this:
P_OUTPUTTEXT := trim(P_OUTPUTTEXT) || ', ' || trim(V_TEXT);

Where V_TEXT contains the next GHS text, so for instance Causes serious eye irritation.
What works
If the procedure COMMON.GetGHSInformation() is called directly, everything works as you would expect.
What doesn't work
The goal of this GetGHSInformation() method is to use it in other procedures, possibly even originating at a different schema.
I have another procedure, let's say
OtherSchema.DoSomethingGHSRelated()

that calls COMMON.GetGHSInformation().
While building the P_OUTPUTTEXT variable the logic throws a ORA-06502 PL/SQL error.
Declarations
The impacted variables are defined like this:
P_OUTPUTTEXT IN OUT VARCHAR2

V_TEXT     VARCHAR2(2000);

Question
The logic defined by COMMON.GetGHSInformation() works fine if called directly, how come it fails if called from another context?

check manually that the length of the generated message for the passed in codes don't exceed the 2000 bytes...

Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for your sample data; the CREATE PROCEDURE statements for your procedure(s); details of how you are calling the procedure; the full error message; and the expected output. If you do not give a way of replicating the problem (and say that it only happens sometimes) then the question is hard to answer (or unanswerable).

If you have the minimal example:
DECLARE
  value VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  value := '12345';
  value := value || '678901';
END;
/

Then the output is:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 5

This is because we defined a string that could have at most 10 characters (2000 in your question) and we tried to set it to a value that has 11 characters.

If V_TEXT is defined as VARCHAR2(2000) then when you get to more than 2000 bytes of characters you will get an ORA-06502 error.
To solve it, either:

Increase the size of V_TEXT (and make sure your strings will not exceed the new limit);

Change V_TEXT to be a CLOB; or

Limit the procedure to only put a maximum of 2000 characters into V_TEXT.
IF LENGTH(P_OUTPUTTEXT) + 2 + LENGTH(trim(V_TEXT)) <= 2000 THEN
  P_OUTPUTTEXT := P_OUTPUTTEXT || ', ' || trim(V_TEXT);
ELSE
  RETURN P_OUTPUTTEXT || ', ...';
END IF;



fiddle

An important thing to note is that it works fine if called directly. So it's not the case that the texts are too large after concat.

@kdb Then please provide a [MRE] that allows us to replicate the problem. If the problem is being called indirectly then the problem is in the procedure that performs the indirect call - again, you need to show the code to allow us to replicate the problem.

I found it, the variable that is passed to the procedure, the one that becomes P_OUTPUTTEXT, was too small. I made it much larger and now it works.
You're answer is the correct way of thinking so I will accept it.
